# Clustering markers from GeoJSON after adding data to layer in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, clustering, markers, layer-switcher

I am trying to add clusters in my leaflet map. I use `overlayMaps` which helps to choose one of the active layers, and in that case I want my marker to be a cluster. But it is not clustering. Again  when I am trying with making any `overlayMaps` variable and put all the data its working the marker are cluster.

I want to show cluster in the map when the layer is active.

Plugin used: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster

```
var cluster = L.markerClusterGroup();
var geo = L.geoJSON(dataview, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.tags.name);
  },
});
geo.addTo(cluster);
var overlayMaps = {
  tourism: tourism,
  hospital: geo,
};
//add the layer control option
L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain a bit more about "working fine" and "not working".

Answer (score 2):

From what i can understand, your layer is not showing when you try to add it through the layer control.
Your code was almost right, you just needed to add `cluster` to `overlayMaps` instead of `geo`.
This code should work for you.

```
var cluster = L.markerClusterGroup();
var geo = L.geoJSON(dataview, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.tags.name);
  },
});
geo.addTo(cluster);
var overlayMaps = {
  tourism: tourism,
  hospital: cluster,
};
//add the layer control option
L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```